# How to fix sqlite 'database locked'?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to work with a database and I keep getting an error telling me my database is locked.

```
async def tradeStock(company, price, user, tradeType, dbId, userTwo, numShares):
    if tradeType == "bids":
        tradeTypeOpp = "asks"
    else:
        tradeTypeOpp = "bids"

    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute(f"""UPDATE "{userTwo}" SET share_amount = share_amount - ? WHERE share_company=?""", (numShares, company,))


    c.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM "{userTwo}" WHERE share_company=?""", (company,))
    row = c.fetchone()

    if row:
        c.execute(f"""UPDATE "{user}" SET share_amount = share_amount + ? WHERE share_company=?""", (numShares, company,))

    else:
        c.execute(f"""INSERT INTO "{user}" (share_company, share_amount) VALUES (?, ?)""", (company, numShares,))


    c.execute(f"""DELETE FROM "{tradeTypeOpp}" WHERE id=?""", (dbId,))


    price = int(price)
    numShares = int(numShares)


    if tradeType == "asks":
        c.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = balance - ? WHERE name=?", (str(price * numShares), userTwo,))
        c.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = balance + ? WHERE name=?", (str(price * numShares), user,))
    if tradeType == "bids":
        c.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = balance - ? WHERE name=?", (str(price * numShares), user,))
        c.execute("UPDATE users SET balance = balance + ? WHERE name=?", (str(price * numShares), userTwo,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

After looking online I saw posts saying to commit() throughout but that didn't change anything.

Comment: A mistake I make very often: modifying the database in DB Browser for SQLite and not writing the changes. This will hold a lock.

Comment: What do you mean by writing the changes? I have had this before and fixed it by just closing db browser but this time it happens if i close it.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, I was calling that function from another function that also used the same database and I forgot to add conn.close() to that function before calling this one.